# jquery dialog, prevent postback from calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#TaskCreatorDivButton").click(function () {
            $("#taskCreationForm").dialog(
                {
                    width: "600px"
                }                   
            );
        });
    });
```

**Creating a "Create new Task" form inside a jQuery dialog.**

I have two custom `asp:Calendars` in this jQuery dialog. When I pick a date from the "startDateCalendar" the dialog window closes (*probably caused by a postback*).

I want to be able to pick a startdate and end date, fill in the rest of the form and then close the dialog when I press a button called "Create task", not before. So how do I prevent this?

Im a beginner at this and Im having a hard time to figure this out on my own so please give me a hand.

Comment: Any serverside events are being called?

Comment: Im not sure, maybe AutoPostBackOnSelectionChanged fires? In that case how do I make it false? I have tried the abvious. AutoPostBackOnSelectionChanged = false.

Comment: Did you set OnSelectionChanged event?

Comment: Yes I have an startDateOfTask_SelectionChanged() & endDateOfTask_SelectionChanged()

Comment: Put break point in those methods and see whether they're invoked when you select Date

Comment: Yes it invokes, inside the method I have this code that runs perfectly: "regStart.Text = startDateOfTask.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();" so next time I open the dialog the textbox has the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `return false`?

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TaskCreatorDivButton").click(function () {
        $("#taskCreationForm").dialog(
            {
                width: "600px"
            }                   
        );
        return false; // <-- this may help
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all server side control events, on " Create Task" button click set regStart.Text using jQuery.

Try using [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) instead of ASP.NET calendar control.